# How to check if some of the object values match the predicate in Ramda?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ramda.js

Since there is no `R.some`, how do I implement the following in Ramda?

```
const hasKey = (predicate, object) =>
  Object.keys(object)
    .map(key => object[key])
    .some(predicate);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Since there is no `R.some` …

It's known as [`any`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#any).

> how do I implement the following in Ramda?

You would write

```
const hasKey = (p, o) => R.any(p, R.values(o))
```